# How to add a class to a WooCommerce product within the product loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add multiple bootstrap col classes to this line of code inside the product loop but I have no idea.

```
<li><?php wc_product_class(); ?></li>
```

Can I somehow push my classed into this bit of php and still keep the product applied?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this 
`<li <?php wc_product_class("col-md-4 col-sm-6 custom-class m-4"); ?>></li>`

Answer (score 2):

For this `wc_product_class();` uses two arguments one is class name and other one is product id so just pass your class name as first argument and product id in second one.

you could see the wc_product_class() in /woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

For example your class name is `test` and product id is `143` then just pass `<li><?php wc_product_class('test',143); ?></li>`